# What's the longest UTF-8 encoded character in bytes that is also present in UCS-2?

Tags: unicode, utf-8, ucs2

I'd like to know which Unicode character is both present in UCS-2 and UTF-8 encoding, that has the longest size in bytes in UTF-8.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "UTF-8 character". The closest thing I can think of is a "unicode codepoint encoded in UTF-8".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- UCS-2 can encode only codepoints in the range from U+0000 to U+FFFF
- UTF-8 needs at most 3 bytes to encode values in this range.

So the UCS-2-encodable codepoints with the longest representation in UTF-8 would be U+0800 to U+FFFF.

Comment: @Blank: you've run against the min text limit twice, and each time with good reason: Your body should have contained some actual question text (for example an explanation why you need it) and comments that simply say "thanks" are not encouraged here (you say thanks by simply up-voting a helpful answer). There's no need for name-calling here.

Comment: I disagree.  Firstly, the title contained the entire question.  What use, value or meaning is there in representing *exactly the same information* a second time?  secondly, saying thanks is important.  Upvoting is entirely impersonal.  If the min text limit is chosen to *discourage* thanks then it is, IMO, unwise.  You will also note that it is also ineffective; I still say thanks.  What however also *actually* occurs, rather than not saying thanks, I say thanks, but I'm also *irritated*.  This is the actual outcome.  I return to my view that the min text is unwise.

Comment: @Blank: whether or not it is unwise *could* be discussed on meta (but I'm pretty sure it already has been), but that's the decision that was made. One thing you *could easily* have done in the body is to re-phrase your question. It's not a trivial question and having phrased it in two ways helps both understanding *and* searchability. Remember that your questions are not *only* for yourself.